# c++ class definition in separate file not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, include, header-files

I am trying to make a game in c++ using `SDL2.0` and `visual studio 2010 express edition`. I want to make a class to hold all info about a level, like map structure, starting position, Finish position, power-up locations. This class is used in multiple source files, so I created a new .cpp file in which I would store the class and a .h file that declares the class. The problem is that it doesn't compile. I get the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Game, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  gameMain.cpp
1>c:\users\dennis\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\therealmofinvisiblemazes_game\game\gamemain.cpp(33): error C2079: 'GameMap' uses undefined class 'level'
1>c:\users\dennis\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\therealmofinvisiblemazes_game\game\gamemain.cpp(36): error C2664: 'gameInit' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int *' to 'level *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>  gameLevelObject.cpp
1>  gameInit.cpp
1>c:\users\dennis\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\therealmofinvisiblemazes_game\game\gameinit.cpp(27): error C2027: use of undefined type 'level'
1>          c:\users\dennis\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\therealmofinvisiblemazes_game\game\gamelevelobject.h(3) : see declaration of 'level'
1>c:\users\dennis\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\therealmofinvisiblemazes_game\game\gameinit.cpp(27): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'short' to 'level'
1>          Source or target has incomplete type
1>  Generating Code...
```

The actual game is created as a DLL, so I can add things like a menu, or a video to the body.
These are the sources that cause the error:

gameMain.cpp:

```
//  STD
#include <string>
#include <IOstream>
#include <map>

//  GAME
#include "Global_Includes.h"    //Include all SDL libs
#include "Global_Mapping.h"     //Include object that tells program what to do when this part is finished
#include "Global_Events.h"      //Include object to control events
#include "Global_Screen.h"      //Include object to control screen

//  LOCAL
#include "gameLevelObject.h"    //Include level class
#include "gameInit.h"           //Include function for initialisation

//  DLL EXPORT
#include "gameMain.h"

mapping game(screen* Display, short int Lvl){

    mapping ReturnValue;
    level GameMap;              //Error: Incomplete type
    gameInit(Lvl, Display, &GameMap);
}
```

gameInit.cpp:

```
//  STD
#include <map>

//  GAME
#include "Global_Includes.h"  //Include all SDL libs
#include "Global_Screen.h"    //Include object to control screen
#include "gameLevelObject.h"  //Include level class
#include "gameInit.h"         //Include header so compiler knows where gameInit is defined

bool gameInit(short int lvl, screen* Display, level* object){

    *object = level::level(lvl); //Error: Incomplete type

    return true;
}
```

gameLevelObject.cpp:

```
//  GAME
#include "Global_Includes.h"    //Include all SDL libs

//  STD
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

//  LOCAL
#include "gameLevelObject.h"    //Include header so compiler knows where class level is defined

class level{

    SDL_Surface* total_map;
    int lives;
    int livesMINUS;
    int livesPLUS;
    int position[2];
    std::vector<std::string> map;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > energyTILES; 

public:
    level(short int lvl){\*constructor definition*\}
};
```

gameLevelObject.h:

```
#include <vector>

class level;
```

I read in the book "The programming language c++", written by Bjarne Stroustrup, that this is how you should include files.

The question is: why doesn't the compiler know that `class level` is defined in gameLevelObject.cpp? and why is the function `gameInit` found by the compiler and `class level` not? I used the same method to link them to gameMain.cpp

Comment: The same thing *does* happen in "gameInit.cpp", as shown by the error message. You should put the definition of the class `level` (but not of its members) in the header file. Right now you have only declared its existence there, but you haven't said what it is (thus, it is "incomplete").

Comment: What I mean is that the function 'gameInit' is defined in a separate file but still found by the compiler. I'll change it. What is the difference between the function in a separate file, and a class?

Comment: These things should be covered in detail in your book, so perhaps some section was unclear. If you look at 15.2.2, the bottom of page 424 (the "a header may contain" box) class definitions is a kind of type definition, but the example uses `struct` rather than `class`. The difference between `struct` and `class` is covered in 8.2.3.

Comment: I just tried what you wrote. I defined the class in the header and declared the member functions. Then I defined the functions like this `level::function` in the gameLevelObject.cpp file and it works! thank you